# Mutate does not retrieve the new data when it is executed after a modification of that data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rendering, mutate, swr

I am working on NEXTjs with a frontend component that renders a table with the Estados component, whose data is obtained by calling the endpoint api/estados/administrativos/lista in the backend. In the table, it is possible to make changes and these are saved in a MongoDB database with a call to the actualizarEstado function, then mutate is called to reflect the changes in the table. The issue is that in the development environment everything works as expected: data is loaded, changes are made, and they are reflected in the table; but when switching to the production environment the behavior is different, more specifically, changes are saved in the database but these new data are not reflected in the table at frontend. What could be the problem? At the end, I provide the backend and frontend code.

Frontend code:

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import useSWR, { mutate } from 'swr';
import Estados from '../_components/estados';
import axios from 'axios';

const EstadosAdministrativos = () => {
    const fetcher = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('/api/estados/administrativos/lista')
        const data = await res.json()
        console.log('cargo estados', data.estados)
        return data.estados
    };

    const { data: estados, error } = useSWR('/api/estados/administrativos/lista', fetcher);

    const actualizarEstado = async (data) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/estados/administrativos/upsert/', data);
            mutate('/api/estados/administrativos/lista');

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Configuración de los estados administrativos</h1>
            {error && <p>Ocurrio un error...</p>}
            {!estados ? (
                <p>Cargando...</p>
            ) : (
                <Estados estados={estados} actualizarEstado={actualizarEstado} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default EstadosAdministrativos;
```

Backend code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

import { EstadoAdministrativo } from '@/models/estados';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const GET = async (request) => {
    console.log('hola');
    try {
        const estados = await EstadoAdministrativo.find({});
        console.log(estados);
        return NextResponse.json({ estados });
    } catch (error) {
        NextResponse.json("Fallo al cargar estados administrativos", { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue: according to the NEXTJS 13 documentation, "Route Handlers are statically evaluated by default when using the GET method with the Response object," and later on, "Route handlers are evaluated dynamically when: Using the Request object with the GET method," among others. Therefore, keeping in mind this last premise of NEXTJS 13, I solved the problem with a simple change to the API using the Request object. Attached is the change in the API at backend.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import { EstadoAdministrativo } from '@/models/estados';
//import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'


export async function GET(request) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
    try {
        const estados = await EstadoAdministrativo.find({})

        return NextResponse.json({ estados, status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: "Fallo al cargar estados" },
            { status: 401 }
        );
    }
}
```